# The version of Tcl/Tk in use may be unstable

Tags: macos, activetcl

When I opened up my python IDLE 2.7 on my mac I received a warning.
WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
I installed activetcl as I saw on the python website but I am still getting the warning. Is there something else that I must do after I installed activetcl to get the warning to go away?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but for future users stumbling upon this page, here is the bug report for this issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue10907

Patch to fix this can be downloaded from here:http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Answer (score 0):

It means you don't have a new version of ActiveTCL. It's probably because you are on an old version of Mac OS. You'll need to install a new version of ActiveTCL from the link that the warning provided you.